# actions of $S4$ to $\mathbb{Q}(x,y)$

Tags: field-theory, galois-theory

Let $\mathbb{Q}(x,y)$ be rational function field.

$D4$ acts on $\mathbb{Q}(x,y)$  and it's fixed field(sets of elements of $\mathbb{Q}(x,y)$ which does not change under the action of $D4$) is $\mathbb{Q}(x^2,y^2)$ .

then, I wonder what is the fixed field of $S4$?
$D4$ can be regarded as subgroup of $S4$, so certainly acts on $\mathbb{Q}(x,y)$.

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Which action?${}$